# Javascript-How Can i Highlight array of elements that matches with form User input textarea in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, highlight

Sorry,i dont now how to ask question clearly,We have Array of elements like following:

```
[' 64 dollars ', ' $6k billion ', ' 7 million']
```

User enters a text like "I have 64 dollars and my brother has $6k billion is 7 million"

In HTML page it needs to display the TEXTAREA value along with highlighted matched array elements. I've tried many like RegEx, String methods.

Please suggest me the code to do this.

Comment: Share your tried codes.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean `along with highlighted matched array` and not that the text is highlighted INSIDE the textarea then this code will work.

```js
var arr = [' 64 dollars ', ' \\$6k billion ', ' 7 million']; // notice the double escape
var str = $("#x").val();
var re = new RegExp(arr.join("|"), "g"); // create a a | b | c regex
// console.log(re, str.match(re));
str.match(re).forEach(function(match, i) { // loop over the matches
  str = str.replace(match, function replace(match) { // wrap the found strings
    return '<em>' + match + '</em>';
  });
});
$("#output").html(str);
```

```css
em { background-color:yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="x">I have 64 dollars and my brother has $6k billion is 7 million</textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: great work, you managed to highlight without a external library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example with regular expressions

```js
$(function(){
  $('.example').highlightWithinTextarea({
    highlight: /64 dollars?|\$6k billion?|7 million/gi,
    className: 'highlight'
  });
});
```

```css
.example{
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
}

.highlight{
  background-color:tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.css">

<textarea class="example">I have 64 dollars and my brother has $6k billion is 7 million</textarea>
```

Comment: Seriously, writing a plugin for this?

Comment: lol found it on https://github.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea

Comment: 380 lines of code. And I was annoyed I had 4 lines instead of 2 <shakes head>

Comment: haha I got it all under 20 lines not counting the underlying script/css

Comment: I do notice now that your textarea is live  - that is also pretty cool. Not sure if that was the specification but interesting

Comment: Ya its pretty snappy library I didn't even know haha.