# Highlighting all occurrences of specific words in a paragraph from an array of keywords

Tags: javascript, highlight

I have a long paragraph and need to highlight keywords contained in an array. I am able to loop through the array and highlight the first occurrence of each word in the paragraph.  I am unable to highlight subsequent occurrences, however.

This is very close to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203533/javascript-how-can-i-highlight-array-of-elements-that-matches-with-form-user-inp).
In the example below, I am trying to find and highlight all occurrences of 'dog' and 'field'.
This works for finding all occurrences of each word because of the `"g"` flag.

```
var re = new RegExp(arr.join("|"), "g")
console.log('keywords are ' + re);
console.log('The matches are ' + str.match(re));
```

But I'm not sure if and where there should be a `"g"` flag within the `replace`.

```html
<p id="x"></p>
```

```
<script>
var arr = ("The dog ran through the field.  The dog ate."); //paragraph from which to search
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = arr;

var words = ["dog", "field"]; //array of keywords

var str = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML;
var re = new RegExp(words.join("|"), "gi"); // create a a | b | c regex
console.log(words);
console.log(re, str.match(re));
console.log('keywords are ' + re);
console.log('The matches are ' + str.match(re));
str.match(re).forEach(function(match, i) { // loop over the matches
  str = str.replace(match, function replace(match) { // wrap the found strings
    return '<em>' + match + '</em>';
  });
});
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = str

</script>
```

```css
em { background-color:yellow }
```

I have tried using `str.replace(/match/g, function(match, i)`. This doesn't error but it removes all highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't need `match(re).forEach`, Just use `replace(re)` alone

```js
var arr = ("The dog ran through the field.  The dog ate."); //paragraph from which to search
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = arr;

var words = ["dog", "field"]; //array of keywords

var str = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML;
var re = new RegExp(words.join("|"), "gi"); // create a a | b | c regex

str = str.replace(re, function replace(match) { // wrap the found strings
  return '<em>' + match + '</em>';
});

document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = str
```

```html
<p id="x"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using **RegExp** constructor for matching globally and using that for variable for replacing

```
  var glob = new RegExp(match, "g");
  str = str.replace(glob, function replace(match) { // wrap the found strings
    return '<em>' + match + '</em>';
  });
```

sample working code

```js
var arr = ("The dog ran through the field.  The dog ate."); //paragraph from which to search
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = arr;

var words = ["dog", "field"]; //array of keywords

var str = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML;
var re = new RegExp(words.join("|"), "gi"); // create a a | b | c regex
console.log(words);
console.log(re, str.match(re));
console.log('keywords are ' + re);
console.log('The matches are ' + str.match(re));
str.match(re).forEach(function(match, i) { // loop over the matches
  var glob = new RegExp(match, "g");
  str = str.replace(glob, function replace(match) { // wrap the found strings
    return '<em>' + match + '</em>';
  });

});
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = str
```

```css
em { background-color:yellow }
```

```html
<p id="x"></p>
<script>


</script>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NQWOqa

Comment: Using ["dog", "", "field"] will freeze your code